# Calculating straight line values in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with 2 columns: date and total water usage. The dataset produces the folowing graph

[image]

This grapgh isn't exactly what i'm looking for so i decided to instead add a straight line that shows a gradual increase from 1968 to 2003. I did this in excel and got the following graph

[image]

Here the green line is a straight line introduced from 1968 - 2003 while the gray line is the original line

Is there a way i can do the same thing in python to end up with the same graph? Such as curve fitting. I want to calculate the total usage values for the intermediate dates using a straight line. I know that straight line has an equation: y = mx + c. 
In this case x is my date and y is my total usage value. So when I fit a straight line to datapoints I have to calculate m and c. How can i implement this in python?

Below is my sample dataset:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'Date': [1970, 1975, 1980, 1985, 1990, 1995, 2000, 2005,2010],
'Total usage': [50, 50.2, 50.3,50.6, 80, 81, 90,91]

}) 

df.plot()
```

Comment: Please share the code that you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't modify the original data points but you can overlay a curve that best fits your data, or smooth any sudden change between sample or points.
First prepare your X & Y data into Numpy arrays, and modify the order of the attached code to get the curve you think is best.

***Most likely a higher order will result into a better looking curve.***

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

points = np.array([(1, 1), (2, 4), (3, 1), (9, 3)])
# get x and y vectors
x = points[:,0]
y = points[:,1]

order = 5

# calculate polynomial
z = np.polyfit(x, y, order)
f = np.poly1d(z)

# calculate new x's and y's
x_new = np.linspace(x[0], x[-1], 50)
y_new = f(x_new)

plt.plot(x,y,'o', x_new, y_new)
plt.xlim([x[0]-1, x[-1] + 1 ])
plt.show()
```